# Deleting menu from ActionBar

Tags: android, menu, bottomnavigationview

I faced with the following problem:

I use `BottomNavigationView` in my program. I added elements to it by creating a menu and then added it. But now this menu is also shown on the screen (there are 3 dots on `ActionBar` (unfortunately I don't know how they are called)).

But there's no need in this menu. How can I remove it from `ActionBar`?

Comment: Hi Sergei, please provide more details about your question. I recommend to read the following post before: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want this menu just delete from your code the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is clear the menu before inflating the new menu XML.

Like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
}
```